# MPLAB Mindi for SIMetrix/SIMPLIS simulation

Tags: power-electronics, simulation

I'm considering this tool as a replacement for SIMetrix/SIMPLIS for the simulation of DC-DC converter feedback loop response.

I would appreciate answers to questions as follows:

- MPLAB Mindi seems free (as in beer), without limits in circuit size / complexity? (such as those imposed by SIMetrix/SIMPLIS Elements, that's the free flavour of SIMetrix/SIMPLIS). Is that correct?
- Is the MPLAB Mindi's IDE in line to that of the "new generation" MPLAB? (I dislike that IDE).
- How do these two compare in terms of usability? (I would like to know this from anyone who has used both.)
- Do these two tools use the same file format for schematics?

I'd also appreciate any other words of advice from people who has used both of these tools.

Comment: You are asking for opinions, mostly, and each of these can be easily found by simply downloading the software and "getting a feel" for yourself.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with SIMetrix/SIMPLIS that such exercise would be very conclusive on its own. I plan to do that with both, but I think any comments here would be very useful for it.

Comment: Well, I can tell you it's not unlimited, it has the same limitations as its cousin. Which makes sense, if you think about it.

Comment: Thanks. Sure it does make sense. I would've expected that this is mentioned somewhere, but that's a different story, of course.